# EJB lookup failed or any context lookup failed Weblogic returns weblogic.socket.UnrecoverableConnectException: [Login failed for an unknown reason:

Tags: java, weblogic, ejb-3.0, jdeveloper

```
javax.naming.CommunicationException [Root exception is weblogic.socket.UnrecoverableConnectException: 
[Login failed for an unknown reason: 
Caused by: weblogic.socket.UnrecoverableConnectException: 
[Login failed for an unknown reason:
```

The code for client is this :

```
package com.mygrp.macropnt;

import com.mygrp.macropnt.ejb.ABCUpdtNewSessionEJBBean;
import java.util.Hashtable;
import java.util.List;

import javax.naming.Context;
import javax.naming.InitialContext;
import javax.naming.NamingException;

public class ABCUpdtNewSessionEJBBeanClient {
public static void main(String [] args) {
    try {
        final Context context = getInitialContext();
        /ABCUpdtNewSessionEJBBean ABCUpdtNewSessionEJBBean = (ABCUpdtNewSessionEJBBean)context.lookup("MacroPointIntegration-MacroPointDAO-ABCUpdtNewSessionEJBBean#com.mygrp.macropnt.ejb.ABCUpdtNewSessionEJBBean");
        ABCUpdtNewSessionEJBBean ABCUpdtNewSessionEJBBean = (ABCUpdtNewSessionEJBBean)context.lookup("jdbc.cnTPSDS");

        for (ABCUpdt ABCupdt : (List<ABCUpdt>)ABCUpdtNewSessionEJBBean.getABCUpdtFindAll()) {
            printABCUpdt(ABCupdt);
        }
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private static void printABCUpdt(ABCUpdt ABCupdt) {
    System.out.println( "version = " + ABCupdt.getVersion() );
    System.out.println( "mpluKey = " + ABCupdt.getMpluKey() );
}

private static Context getInitialContext() throws NamingException {
    Hashtable env = new Hashtable();
    // WebLogic Server 10.x connection details
    env.put( Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "weblogic.jndi.WLInitialContextFactory" );
    env.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, "t3://127.0.0.1:7101");

    return new InitialContext( env );
}
}
```

Using `wlst.cmd` I was able to connect to WEblogic using t3 protocol. Also I confirmed in the jndi tree my ejb is present. So can some please point to a place to look for solution to this problem.

Thanks,
Muqeet

Comment: possible solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18566225/weblogic-socket-unrecoverableconnectexception

Comment: Tried didnt work. even ip address didnt help.

Comment: Is your port correct? One of my rookie mistakes was that I tried to connect to admin server instead of managed server, where my application was deployed.

Comment: Yes. 7101 is for defaultserver listen port.

Comment: Your code looks ok. Can you deploy your app to different weblogic to verify that it is not damaged? Alternatively deploy some 3rd party demo on your weblogic and test it.

Comment: Does the server you're trying to connect to have errors in its log file? e.g. `<domain>/servers/<your server>/logs`